# Implementing facebook like button data-href with IP address

Tags: c#, facebook

I was success full in implementing Facebook like for my website which had a domain name..But when i want to implement it using an ip address where i have hosted it...It does not work.

Any idea on how to achieve this

Below is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function(d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "/js/alllocalFb.js#xfbml=1&appId=138257749685264";
             ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
         } (document));
    </script>
```

And here is my like button div `<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://192.168.1.5:8484/" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450"
                    data-show-faces="false">`

Comment: Why downvote this question? - care to comment?

Comment: _"It does not work"_ is not an error.

Comment: @CodeCaster what doesnot work can u please elaborate...and can u please letme know why is the down vote

Answer (score 0):

> I was success full in implementing Facebook like for my website which had a domain name..But when i want to implement it using an ip address where i have hosted it...It does not work.

I think that might be intentional.

The whole Open Graph is based on identifying objects based on their URL. Yes, an URL with an IP address instead of a domain name is technically a valid one – but Facebook likes to be able (I guess) to block spammy sites based on their domain name. Domain blocked == p.i.t.a. for the spammer, has to get new domain. Just switching to another IP address – usually easier and done more quickly.

---

Although, when I input your IP address into the generator on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/, I see a like button and “one person likes this” …